# Iterate through implementations of an interface and invoke a method

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have several implementations of an interface:

```
public interface IDemoInterface
{
    void DemoMethod();
}

public class DemoClass1 : IDemoInterface
{
    public void DemoMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DemoClass1");
    }

}

public class DemoClass2 : IDemoInterface
{
    public void DemoMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DemoClass2");
    }

}
```

Now, I am trying to define an array of such implementations and for each implementation call the interface method. Essentially, do something like this (what follows is a NON-WORKING code -- just an illustration of what I am trying to do):

```
public static void Run()
{
    var demoClasses = { DemoClass1, DemoClass2};

    foreach (var demoClass in demoClasses)
    {
        var implementation = demoClass as IDemoInterface;
        implementation.DemoMethod();
    }
}
```

What is the best way to accomplish it? Is using Reflection the only way?

Comment: Aside from the few syntax issues, what's wrong with the way you're doing it now?

Comment: Do you want to initialize the implementations on your own,what is not working according to you?

Comment: You make a array or list of IDemoInterface, assigned or add the Instances and then itterate over them. That is indeed the simple, obvious way to do what you describe, Unless you somehow meant something else, like having a list of all of those instances ever created in the porgramm without having to manually fill it (I can think of a way using Abstract classes, the constructor and weak reference).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your example, it looks like you're not trying to loop through *instances* of classes that implement your interface. You're trying to loop through the types themselves. I'm basing it on this...

```
var demoClasses = { DemoClass1, DemoClass2};
```

...and in your question `DemoClass` and `DemoClass2` are class *types*, not instances of types.

You could start with a collection of types and then create an instance of each type, like this. (You could also use reflection to find the class types that implement your interface.)

```
var types = new Type[] {typeof(DemoClass1), typeof(DemoClass1)};
foreach (var type in types)
{
    if (typeof(IDemoInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    {
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IDemoInterface;
        instance.DemoMethod();
    }
}
```

That will work, but there's a huge limitation: Each class must have a default constructor. Or if you're going to call a constructor, they would all need to have the same one.

In other words, if one of these classes has a constructor like this:

```
public DemoClass1(string connectionString){
```

then `Activator.CreateInstance` will blow up unless you give it the values to pass into the constructor. But if you have an array of types and they have different constructors then it's pretty much impossible to do that. And you don't want to paint yourself into a corner where you have to write classes that can only have empty constructors.

When you have an interface and classes that implement that interfaces, and you want to get instances of those classes, a dependency injection container (Ioc container) can be helpful. If you haven't used it there's a tiny bit of a learning curve, but it's a very useful tool to have in your box. Here's an example (this is from [my blog](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/02/21/dependency-injection-resolving-collections.html)) of configuring a [Windsor](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/README.md) container to "register", or declare several implementations of an interface.

(If you're not familiar with this it's going to seem totally out of nowhere, which is why I also linked to Windsor's documentation.)

```
public class DependencyRegistration : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));
        container.Register(Component.For<OrderValidator>());

        container.Register(
            Component.For<IOrderValidator,AddressValidator>()
                .Named("AddressValidator"),
            Component.For<IOrderValidator,OrderLinesValidator>()
                .Named("OrderLinesValidator"),
            Component.For<IOrderValidator,ProductStateRestrictionsValidator>()
                .Named("ProductStateRestrictionsValidator")
            );
    }
}
```

In this example I've told this "container" that there are three classes that implement `IOrderValidator`.

Now this container can "resolve", or return, an array of implementations of `IOrderValidator`. Notice this line near the top:

```
container.Register(Component.For<OrderValidator>());
```

Here's that class:

```
public class OrderValidator : IOrderValidator
{
    private readonly IOrderValidator[] _subValidators;

    public OrderValidator(IOrderValidator[] subValidators)
    {
        _subValidators = subValidators;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationMessage> GetValidationMessages(Order order)
    {
        var validationMessages = new List<ValidationMessage>();
        foreach(var validator in _subValidators)
        {
            validationMessages.AddRange(validator.GetValidationMessages(order));
        }
        return validationMessages;
    }
}
```

Notice that in the constructor there is an array of `IOrderValidator`. If I were to call

```
var validator = container.Resolve<OrderValidator>();
```

the container would create an instance of `OrderValidator`. It would detect that the constructor requires an array of `IOrderValidator`, so it would create instances of all of those other classes and place them in the array.

If any of those classes also had constructors that required other values or classes, and I told the container how to create those, it would create those as needed in order to be able to create the implementations of `IOrderValidator`.

The result is that I can have numerous implementations of a class, each with different constructor dependencies of their own, and I can create a collection of those implementations.

This answer doesn't go far toward really telling you how to do this, but hopefully it shows where to find the tools to accomplish this sort of thing. DI containers are very useful tools when used correctly. It's common practice in large applications and even small ones because it makes it easier to manage lots and lots of class types that may be nested inside one another while keeping it sane and understandable. It also helps us to write classes that are smaller and easier to unit test.

In addition to Windsor some other containers are Autofac, Unity, SimpleInjector, and the DI container that's included with ASP.NET Core applications.

Comment: First of all: wow! Such a detailed response in such a short time. This is the stuff I was looking for: `Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IDemoInterface`, so I am accepting your response as the answer to my question.

Comment: Question: what if I didn't have an interface and my two classes were static, but I would be able to guarantee that `DemoMethod` static method would be there. Any way to have the same loop?

Comment: Thank you. If you could guarantee that the static methods existed and would all have the same signature then you could create an array of those method, like `methods = new Action[] { staticClass1.DemoMethod, staticClass1.DemoMethod2, staticClass2.DemoMethod};` In this case they wouldn't need to have the same name or be implementations of an interface. They would just need to have the same signature. If it's an method that takes an argument or returns something it could be `Action<string>` or `Func<DateTime, int>` etc.

Comment: Got it, thank you. So no way to start with a collection of `{DemoClass1, DemoClass2}` if the classes are static, right?

Comment: I wouldn't say no way, because there are ways to get a method from a class using reflection if you know that the class has a method with that name and with that signature. But it almost certainly wouldn't be beneficial. If we're going to use code this way it would be better not to use static classes. If we have no choice but to use static classes then we could create non-static classes with interfaces (back to where we started) and the methods in those classes could call the static methods in the static classes.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is mostly correct:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var demoClasses = new List<IDemoInterface> {new DemoClass1(), new DemoClass2()};

    foreach (var demoClass in demoClasses)
    {
        demoClass.DemoMethod();
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Why would you use `List<object>` to convert those back to `IDemoInterface`? Just use `List<IDemoInterface>` and remove those conversions

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Oh, good point! i misread the question and thought he had a list of different types. i updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Although Scott Hannen's answer was closer to what I was looking for, your answer would work too and it definitely adds value, so I am upvoting it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

From the question, it is not clear for me if you wish to initialize the types yourself, or if you want to do it like [Rufus's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48716079/3231537) answer.

However, if you do not know the implementation beforehand, you could theoretically scan for them, and retrieve all the types

```
// can throw a ReflectionTypeLoadException in case not all dlls are known
private static IEnumerable<Type> GetImplementationsOf<TInterface>() {
  var interfaceType = typeof( TInterface );
  return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .Select( assembly => assembly.GetTypes().Where( type => !type.IsInterface && interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom( type ) ) )
    .SelectMany( implementation => implementation );
}
```

This code will return a `IEnumerable<Type>` that matches the generic type parameter, and which isn't an interface (though theoretically, this part you could leave for your consumer to handle)

Afterwards, you can run through the list of types and create an instance of them and run your code, like so:

```
var types = GetImplementationsOf<IDemoInterface>();
foreach (var type in types) {
  // will throw an exception in case there is no parameterless constructor
  var impl = (IDemoInterface) Activator.CreateInstance( type );
  impl.DemoMethod();
}
```